# How to store a function into a store variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a component, i want that my variable from the store is equal a function in order to use it.

I create my function like that:

```
makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));
```

It is a function from material-ui.

And i get the value like that in my store:

```
this.state = {
  classes: makeStyles()
};
```

So i'm expected that i can use it like: `this.state.classes.root` but i don't works (it compile but don't works)

Thats my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      classes: makeStyles()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar className="red">
            // for example, here i would like to use it like: this.state.classes.root
            <div className="blue">
              <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <div className="green">
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    access_token: state.access_token
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar));
```

Instead of

```
 <Toolbar className="red">
```

I would like to have:

```
<Toolbar className={this.state.classes.root}>
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To use JavaScript values, you have do this way:

```js
<Toolbar className={this.state.classes.root}>
```

Comment: @Kan But you have `className="this.state.classes.root"` in your code.

Comment: I just eddited it. I wrote it wrong but the error is not that

Answer (score 0):

Check by changing your code as:
(Changes are commented in CAPITAL)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

// INITIALIZE THE makeStyles INTO ANOTHER VARIABLE, HERE I USED useStyles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // NOW CALL useStyles IN THE state
    this.state = {
      classes: useStyles()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar className="red">
            // for example, here i would like to use it like: this.state.classes.root
            <div className="blue">
              <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <div className="green">
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    access_token: state.access_token
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar));
```

Please comment if in case you face any problem in implementing the solution.

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Fine, then you can try making your component, "Function Component". Function components are (old stateless components + new React Hooks especially for state).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Material-UI styles [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api). Here's their short-form example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Your code would look like the following. Note I've converted it to a functional component so it can use Hooks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

function NavBar({access_token}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar className="red">
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <div className="green">
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    access_token: state.access_token
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you assign the `this.state.classes.root` value to `className`, I guess you intended to assign it to `style`?

Comment: Yes but it my className or myStyle don't take the value. It compile but it don't take the good value, it's like default value

Comment: So what do you suggest ?

Comment: You say it didn't work to use ‘style‘? I would create a CSS class and assign it to className using a string value.